# Intro to polymorphism 101 java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm making a small RPG. There is an Item class which is the parent of each item in the game. These items could be Potion (which is a class) or Bandage (which is a class).

The Item class looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
int qty;
String name;
Hero hero1;

public void passHero(Hero hero1)
{
    this.hero1 = hero1;
}

public void use()
{
    if(qty == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You have no more of this item to use.");
    }
    else
    {    
        qty--;
    }
}

public void addInv(int value)
{
    qty = qty + value;
}
}
```

A method for passing in the Hero class.
A method for using an item.
A method for adding to the inventory of the item.

This method activates these item classes:

```
public void initializeItemInventory()
{
    items[0] = new Potion();
    items[1] = new Bandage();
}
```

And this method would theoretically print all the items and their quantities:

```
public void useInventory()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<items.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter: " + i + " for " + items[i].name);

    }

    int response = input.nextInt();
    items[response].use();

}
```

The Potion class, as an example, has an instance variable like:

```
String name = "Potion";
```

So my question. Why isn't the name variable from Potion being called correctly in the `useInventory` method. It returns `null` which tells me it's returning the parent class `Item` name, and not the name of the individual subclass variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java inheritance overriding instance variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933555/java-inheritance-overriding-instance-variable)

Comment: @aruisdante suggestions?

Comment: Side note on your design: do you think that an item *owns* a hero?

Comment: Read the duplicate question and its answers. And the other question and its answers that the duplicate is a duplicate of. If you're still unclear, add additional details to your question as to what in those duplicates don't answer your question.

Comment: Well, the first question that came to my mind is: why does the `Item` care about `Hero`? A hero might "know" his inventory, but the Item shouldn't care about his carrier.

Comment: @Tom Actually it makes more sense that way to some degree; a hero shouldn't need to know how to use items, items should know how to act on a hero. That doesn't seem to be the design as current, but it actually is a pretty sensical OO design choice. Certainly it could (probably should) be implemented as `useMe(hero)` rather than storing a hero reference however. Not really relevant to the OP's question though.

Comment: @aruisdante A `#use` method *might* need a hero to act on, but then it should passed only in that method (e.g. "throwing" items to react on a different hero). Binding the item to a hero is still unnecessary. `Not really relevant to the OP's question however.` No one asserted that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Inheritance - instance variables overriding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464222/java-inheritance-instance-variables-overriding)

Comment: @aruisdante I've been thinking a lot what you said, of `Item` not owning `Hero` which is fair. Keep in mind im new to programming and Java is my first language. How else can a variable like, say, the hero's HP be obtained from another class, say, the `Item` class without passing `Hero` into `Item`. The method needs to occur within `Item`, not inside the main line. Does that make sense? It's just it feels like passing Hero to Item is the only way to go.

Comment: It shouldn't access the health of Hero directly; Instead, `Hero` should provide a way to add a buff/debuff to a stat (say, `Hero.modifyHealth(adjustment)`).  The `Item` class would then call this method and provide it with the amount to adjust health by. `Hero` then does whatever is needed to actually implement that modification. Think of the interaction as a 'conversation' between the objects; The Hero says "hey Item, I want to use you on me", to which the Item replies "Ok Hero, you should modify this stat by this amount".

Comment: Very good. Makes sense.

Comment: Although...whats the downside of referring directly to a local variable of an instance as opposed to using a method to refer to it:
hero1.heroHP
or hero1.getHP(); why is the latter preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Item
{
  int qty;
  String name;
  ...
```

The `Item` class already has `name`, and that's what you access from an `Item`-typed variable:

```
items[0].name
```

So if you have

```
public class Potion extends Item
{
  String name = "Potion";
  ...
```

then the `Potion` class has *two* `name` fields:

```
Potion p = new Potion();
System.out.println(p.name);
System.out.println((Item) p).name);
```

As you say, you want *polymorphism*, but it only applies to *methods*. Therefore you need a getter:

```
public class Item
{
  String name;
  public String getName() { return name; }
  ...
```

In the `Potion` subclass you may have

```
public class Potion extends Item
{
  public Potion() { this.name = "Potion"; }
  ...
```

and `items[0].getName()` will now work as expected.

### Additional note

I'll add this to show a bit of the power of polymorphism.

If you happened to have the `name` property always the same for all the instances of the same class, you could easily refactor your getter-based solution by completely eliminating the need to store a `name` variable:

```
public class Item
{
  public String getName() { return "Generic item"; }
  ...
```

---

```
public class Potion extends Item
{
  @Override public String getName() { return "Potion"; }
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring a new variable in your subclass like "String name = "Potion";"
Use your constructor to pass the value to your superclass, something like this:

```
// the Item supuerclass has one constructor
public Item(name) {
  this.name = name;
} 

// the Potion subclass has one constructor
public Potion() {
  super("Potion");
}
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you now have a duplicate `name` string in every `Item` class instance, even though they all point to the same object. This would make sense if `name` was relatively unique per item. If they're basically just a duplication of the class name however (as in the OP's design), it would more efficient to just have a single static name shared by all instances of the class.