# Inheritance with variable

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMSun.jpg)Referring to below program, as per my understanding it should print value of a as 20, as run time we get class B object but it is printing a value as 10. Can someone please help me understand this? Thanks!
[Check code here]

Comment: can you edit and add the code

Comment: Please check the image attached

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933555/java-inheritance-overriding-instance-variable  , short answer would be "This demonstrates that there is one object with two distinct fields called a ... and you can get hold of both of their values, if the access permits it"

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing. Remvoe the duplicate `int a = 10;` definition, and mark `a` as protected in Class A

For more details on shadowing in Java (or in general) check out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092099/what-is-variable-shadowing-used-for-in-a-java-class)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not polymorphic in Java. Same variable declared in subclass does not override the value in super class.